# Tangent vector of geodesic on sphere trough points $(a,b,c)$ and $(d,e,f)$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, tangent-spaces

I am seeking the unit vector $v=(x,y,z)$ tangent at $p$ to the geodesic on sphere connecting $p=(a,b,c)$ and $q=(d,e,f)$. The curve is orientated from $p$ to $q$.

Once the tangent vector is ortogonal to the point vectors, so I must have

$$\begin{cases}ax+by+cz=0\\
x^2+y^2+z^2=1\end{cases}$$

I need more two equations to get the vector, could you help me?

**The aim is to prove that the application $(p,q)\mapsto v$ is continuous.**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: At what point of the geodesic you want this tangent vector? Do you require a unit tangent vector? And what do you know about geodesics? (it'd be easier to answer, knowing that)

Comment: (1) At $p$; (2) Yes!; (3) Shortest distance; on sphere, portions of great arcs. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: There is no calculus or differential geometry here. If you want the great circle through $p$ passing through $q$ ($q\ne -p$), it lies in the plane with normal vector $p\times q$. The tangent vector to a great circle will lie in that plane and be orthogonal to the position vector. How do you find a vector in that plane orthogonal to $p$?

Comment: Thank you really much, Prof. Shifrin. So I think that I must have $\langle v,p\times q\rangle=\langle v,p\rangle=0$, $||v||=1$. Perfect. I just have a doubt on direction. I'd like to get the tangent on direction from $p$ to $q$, could you help me once? Thank you

Comment: This will be built in if you think about using the cross product once more! Draw some pictures and use your right hand! :)

Comment: Thank once again!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get $v$ is to first consider the vector $w: = q-p$, which points in the right direction, but it's not tangent. One can check that its projection onto the tangent space $T_p \mathbb{S}^2$
$$ v := w - (w \cdot p) p $$
is the tangent vector we want.

The outcome is the same if we just consider the projection of $q$ onto $T_p \mathbb{S}^2$: $v = q - (q \cdot p) p$.

Comment: Thank you much!